# Expand/create pandas columns from grouped rows by concatenating subid value and other column names

Tags: pandas, join, pandas-groupby

I would like to create new columns from a panda dataframe by grouping based on a column and concatenating a subindex (in another column) with two other column names. This is best illustrated with an example. Say this is my input dataframe:

```
                  filename     sub_id    x    y
0  2019-07-29T16-01-33.jpg          0  731  343
1  2019-07-29T16-01-33.jpg          1  741  283
2  2019-07-29T16-01-34.jpg          0  734  407
3  2019-07-29T16-01-34.jpg          1  757  348
4  2019-07-29T16-01-35.jpg          0  741  293
5  2019-07-29T16-01-35.jpg          1  760  380
```

And I want to obtain this:

```
                  filename    x0   y0   x1   y1
0  2019-07-29T16-01-33.jpg   731  343  741  283
1  2019-07-29T16-01-34.jpg   734  407  757  348
2  2019-07-29T16-01-35.jpg   741  293  760  380
```

The `sub_id` value (0 or 1) is appended to the `x` and `y` column names to create new columns and the respective coordinate values transferred accordingly.

I'm assuming I have to use groupby in some way or joins, but not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another method:

```
# create the columns for x0, x1, y0, y1
df_unstacked= df.set_index(['filename', 'sub_id']).unstack(-1)
# rename the column
df_unstacked.columns= [''.join(map(str, c_tup)) for c_tup in df_unstacked.columns]
```

The result is

```
                          x0   x1   y0   y1
filename                                   
2019-07-29T16-01-33.jpg  731  741  343  283
2019-07-29T16-01-34.jpg  734  757  407  348
2019-07-29T16-01-35.jpg  741  760  293  380
```

Comment: This is better than mine. you can also sort if you want to match OP output `df.set_index(['filename', 'sub_id']).unstack(-1).sort_values('sub_id',axis=1)` :) +1

Comment: Why did you delete yours?

Comment: mine looks clumsy, your is far better. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer jottbe and your help anky_91.

Comment: Hmm. In general the `pivot` solutions are often more elegant, because you don't have to set the index manually. If you could have found a way to avoid the `melt` I guess it would be easier to understand (I guess the melt could consume extra ressources if the source dataframe is large).